# Set datetime format in x-axis of Highchart

Tags: datetime, highcharts

I'm trying to implement datetime series chart in highchart. I've provided UNIX timestamp and it plots the data like this for 8 hours of data:

[image]

As you can see, I can't know the date for this chart. I want to show the date in the first point('%e. %b'). Right now when the day changes, it automatically display the date like this for 24 hour:

[image]

This is my implementation right now:

```
      xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        crosshair: true,
        gridLineWidth: 0
      }
```

I tried using formatter like below but it does not display date at all except for the first point:

```
      xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        labels: {
          formatter: function () {
            if (this.isFirst) {
              return Highcharts.dateFormat('%e. %b', this.value);
            }
            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M', this.value);
          }
        },
        crosshair: true,
        gridLineWidth: 0
      }
```

I am trying to write a formatter function which at first point and at midnight, show the date and all other time, it shows the time in HH:mm?

Comment: *"it shows the time in HH:mm"* That's exactly what you've told it to show: `return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M', this.value);` I am not clear what the actual problem/question is.

Comment: @jlbriggs Sorry for not being clear. I want to show the value which shows the data as %e. %b around the midnight. Similar values as you get with default formatter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getHours()` to check the hour of the data value of your axis label, and format accordingly:

```
  labels: {
    formatter: function() {
      if (this.isFirst) {
        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%e. %b', this.value);
      } 
      else {
        var t = new Date(this.value);
        var h = t.getHours();
        return h == 0 
          ? Highcharts.dateFormat('%e. %b', this.value) 
          : Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M', this.value);
      }

    }
  }
```

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/eukr8gtx/